# Angular error: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'object'. I have followed other posts related to this error but have not solved it

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem in Angular that does not allow me to continue.
As the title suggests I tried to follow other posts on this site that reflect my own problem, but I haven't solved it.
I apologize if I still ask this question.

***error**: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'object'*.
The error is found on the following line: let result = response.json (); (see code below)
The code of interest is as follows:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  
import { ProductService } from '../product.service';  
import {FormControl,FormGroup,Validators} from '@angular/forms';  
import { Product } from '../product';  
@Component({  
  selector: 'app-add-product',  
  templateUrl: './add-product.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./add-product.component.css']  
})  
export class AddProductComponent implements OnInit {  

  selectedFiles!: FileList;
  currentFileUpload!:File;
  
  constructor(private productservice:ProductService) { }  
  
  product : Product=new Product();  
  submitted = false;  
  
  ngOnInit() {  
    this.submitted=false;  
  }  

  selectFile(event:any) {  
    const file = event.target.files.item(0);  
   
    if (file.type.match('image.*')) {  
      var size = event.target.files[0].size;  
      if(size > 1000000)  
      {  
          alert("size must not exceeds 1 MB");  
          this.productsaveform.get('photo')!.setValue("");  
      }  
      else  
      {  
        this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;  
      }  
    } else {  
      alert('invalid format!');  
    }  
  
  }     
  
  productsaveform=new FormGroup({  
    prodcode:new FormControl('' , [Validators.required , Validators.minLength(5) ] ),  
    name:new FormControl('' , [Validators.required , Validators.minLength(5) ] ),  
    photo:new FormControl()
  });  
  
  saveProduct(saveProduct: any){  
    this.product=new Product();     
    this.product.prodcode=this.Prodcode!.value;  
    this.product.name=this.Name!.value;  
    console.log(this.product);
    this.submitted = true;  
    this.save();  
  }  
  
    
  
  save() {  
    this.productservice.createProduct(this.product) .subscribe(
    response => {  
      let result = response.json();  //<<<<<<<------------------------------  ERROR
      console.log(result);  
      if(result > 0 )  
      {  
        if(this.selectedFiles != null)  
        {  
          this.currentFileUpload = this.selectedFiles.item(0)!;  
          console.log(this.currentFileUpload);  

          this.productservice.uploadFile(this.currentFileUpload , result).subscribe(  
            res => {  

                let re = res.json();  
                 if(re > 0)  
                 {  
                    alert("file upload successfully ");  
                    this.productsaveform.get('prodcode')!.setValue("");  
                    this.productsaveform.get('name')!.setValue("");  
                    this.productsaveform.get('photo')!.setValue("");  
                 }  
                 else{  
                    alert("error while uploading fie details");  
                 }  
              },  
            err => {  
                  alert("error while uploading fie details");  
              }  
          );  

        }  
      }  
  },  
  error => {  
    console.log("error while saving data in the DB");  
  }  
);  

}  
    
  get Prodcode(){  
    return this.productsaveform.get('prodcode');  
  }

  get Name(){  
    return this.productsaveform.get('name');  
  }  
  
 
}
```

Comment: If you want to serialize the object into a json string, it should be `let result = response.toJson();` - I am not aware of a json() method in angular

Comment: Show the code for `createproduct`. Depending on [how you call it](https://angular.io/guide/http) the value of the observable could already be the deserialized object. I'd also recommend logging out the value of `response`, or inspecting it while debugging, to get an idea of what it has on it.

Comment: Angular, by defect use JSON, I don't know what do you want to acheive make using .json, Are you asking about JSON.stringify() and JSON.Parse()?https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @Kinglish i tried to do this but it doesn't work. I solved; the problem was in the createProduct method, where I had initially put createProduct(product:object): Observable<object> and changed it to createProduct (product:Product): Observable<any>.
So it worked correctly.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior you were right, the problem was in the createProduct method, I had put createProduct (product: object): Observable <object> and instead I had to put createProduct (product:Product): Observable<any>.

Comment: @Eliseo it worked the same, the problem was in the createProduct method, I had put createProduct (product: object): Observable<object> and instead I had to put createProduct (product:Product: Observable<any>.